# Actualizar JFrame a tiempo real

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, update, netbeans-11

los pongo en contexto, estoy practicando haciendo un programa de puntuación de padel y quería hacerlo de tal manera que haya un panel de control que sólo vea yo y otra ventana más presentable que vea el público, es decir que trabajo con 2 JFrames y que uno controla al otro, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es a la hora de actualizar los Labels para los nombres y puntuación ya que al presionar el botón para guardar los datos de las parejas la otra ventana no hace absolutamente nada, ya probé algunas soluciones y nada así que recurro a ustedes a ver si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, les paso a dejar el código de las 2 ventanas:

Ventana 1 o Dashboard

```
package app;

public class Dashboard extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Dashboard() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Contenido = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        txtIntegrante2Pareja2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtIntegrante1Pareja1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtIntegrante2Pareja1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtIntegrante1Pareja2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnGuardarPareja1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnGuardarPareja2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnAbrirMarcador = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Pro Cup Padel");
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setResizable(false);

        Contenido.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        Contenido.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        txtIntegrante2Pareja2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtIntegrante2Pareja2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        Contenido.add(txtIntegrante2Pareja2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 210, 281, 52));
        Contenido.add(txtIntegrante1Pareja1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 130, 281, 52));
        Contenido.add(txtIntegrante2Pareja1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 210, 281, 52));
        Contenido.add(txtIntegrante1Pareja2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 130, 281, 52));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bebas Neue", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Pareja 2");
        Contenido.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(590, 50, 280, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bebas Neue", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Pareja 1");
        Contenido.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 40, 280, -1));

        btnGuardarPareja1.setText("Guardar");
        btnGuardarPareja1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGuardarPareja1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        Contenido.add(btnGuardarPareja1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 300, 100, -1));

        btnGuardarPareja2.setText("Guardar");
        btnGuardarPareja2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnGuardarPareja2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        Contenido.add(btnGuardarPareja2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(690, 300, 100, -1));

        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/pro cup padel_menor.png"))); // NOI18N
        Contenido.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(360, 100, -1, -1));

        btnAbrirMarcador.setText("Abrir maracador");
        btnAbrirMarcador.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAbrirMarcadorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        Contenido.add(btnAbrirMarcador, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(400, 300, 130, -1));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Contenido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Contenido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtIntegrante2Pareja2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                     
    
    //////////////BOTONES/////////////
    //////////////BOTONES/////////////
    //////////////BOTONES/////////////
    
    private void btnGuardarPareja1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Marcador marcador = new Marcador();
        String pareja1 =txtIntegrante1Pareja1.getText() + "  " + txtIntegrante2Pareja1.getText();
        Marcador.lblPareja1.setText(pareja1);
    }                                                 

    private void btnGuardarPareja2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Marcador marcador = new Marcador();
        String pareja2 = txtIntegrante1Pareja2.getText() + "  " + txtIntegrante2Pareja2.getText();
        marcador.lblPareja2.setText(pareja2);
    }                                                 

    private void btnAbrirMarcadorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        Marcador marcador = new Marcador();
        marcador.setVisible(true);
    }                                                

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Dashboard().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel Contenido;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAbrirMarcador;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardarPareja1;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnGuardarPareja2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtIntegrante1Pareja1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtIntegrante1Pareja2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtIntegrante2Pareja1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtIntegrante2Pareja2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Ventana 2 o Marcador

```
package app;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Marcador extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Marcador() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    public void actualizarPantalla(){
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(lblPareja1);
        this.validateTree();
    }  
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        PanelMarcador = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        img = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblPareja1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblPareja2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Marcador");
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1080, 720));

        PanelMarcador.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        PanelMarcador.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1280, 720));
        PanelMarcador.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        img.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        img.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        img.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/pro cup padel.png"))); // NOI18N
        PanelMarcador.add(img, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(650, 100, 390, 290));

        lblPareja1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bebas Neue", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        lblPareja1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblPareja1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPareja1.setText("VOID");
        lblPareja1.setToolTipText("");
        PanelMarcador.add(lblPareja1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 430, 600, 240));

        lblPareja2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Bebas Neue", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        lblPareja2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblPareja2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblPareja2.setText("VOID");
        lblPareja2.setToolTipText("");
        PanelMarcador.add(lblPareja2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(840, 430, 600, 240));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(PanelMarcador, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1920, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(PanelMarcador, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1080, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Marcador.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Marcador.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Marcador.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Marcador.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Marcador().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public static javax.swing.JPanel PanelMarcador;
    private javax.swing.JLabel img;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel lblPareja1;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel lblPareja2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Un JFrame (*Vista*) no debería controlar otro JFrame. Una vista debe ser controlada por un *Controlador*. Si ambas vistas comparten el mismo *Modelo* cuando el controlador actualice el modelo las vistas deben actualizarse.